# Using menu button in phonegap's in app browser android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So my phonegap opens IAB(In App Browser).

How can I modify InAppBrowser.java to give a callback to the menu(settings) key from android?

basically what needs to be done is, if you press the menu button. It injects js into the IAB.

So for you people

```
app.iabRef.addEventListener('backbutton', onBack, false);
app.iabRef.addEventListener('menubutton', onMenu, false);
```

This does NOT work for in app browser.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: did you find a solution or workaround?

Comment: yes I looked in the java code and edited it there. I could make an answer if you like

Comment: is the code available anywhere to look it up? github or so? i could make the make the back button to work via editing some java code but not the settings button

Comment: no I don't have the code online. But I only fixed the back button. The menu button took too long to figure out so I passed on that one for now. But it should relate to what you used for the back button i think. Good luck! Let me now if you found something ^^